# Two Foreign Keys raise "Can' create table" on MySQL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-migrations

I've created a migration file with following content..
It works fine with SQLite but when I switch to MySQL I get an "Can't create table" error (see below).

```
class CreateVisits < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def change
    create_table :visits, :primary_key => :id do |t|
      t.references :user, foreign_key: true
      t.references :visitor, foreign_key: "User"
      t.timestamps
    end
    add_index :visits, [:user_id, :visitor_id], unique: true
  end
end
```

MySQL throws an error:

```
Mysql2::Error: Can't create table 'myapp_development.visits' (errno: 150): 
CREATE TABLE `visits` (
`id` int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, 
`user_id` int, 
`visitor_id` int, 
`created_at` datetime NOT NULL, 
`updated_at` datetime NOT NULL,  
INDEX `index_visits_on_user_id`  (`user_id`),  
INDEX `index_visits_on_visitor_id`  (`visitor_id`), 
CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_09e5e7c20b`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
  REFERENCES `users` (`id`), 
CONSTRAINT `fk_rails_b156c396f4`
FOREIGN KEY (`visitor_id`)
  REFERENCES `visitors` (`id`)
) 

ENGINE=InnoDB
```

Ideas welcome!

Comment: do you have `users` table and `visitors` table created before creating this `visits` table?

Comment: users table has been created before. visits table contains 2 columns: user_id and visitor_id which both are related to 1 record in the users table

Comment: how about the `visitors` table? this looks like mysql is trying to create the reference but couldn't find one of the tables that it's trying to reference to

Comment: there is no visitors table.

Comment: your hint was good, I've changed the reference to an integer and it works. thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

150 error is usually raised when you try to reference a table that doesn't exist.

In your case, you are referencing both foreign keys to the same primary key in the `users` table.

But you can't just use `foreign_key: true` in this case. But you can do it by adding two more lines

```
def change
  create_table :visits, :primary_key => :id do |t|
    t.references :user, references: :visits
    t.references :visitor, references: :visits
    t.timestamps
  end

  add_foreign_key :visits, :users, column: :user_id
  add_foreign_key :visits, :users, column: :visitor_id
end
```